# Prevent connection close with JSoup

Tags: google-app-engine, jsoup, meta-tags, meta

I am **not** much knowledgeable with it comes to networking (i.e. http) or JSoup. I am using JSoup to get meta tag contents from a url. I am getting the error

```
Connection closed unexpectedly by server at URL: http://blahblah
```

Here is my code

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements metas = doc.getElementsByTag("meta");
...
```

How do I "configure" JSoup to just grab the content of the webpage, close the connection, and then proceed to parse the content obtained? I am asking the question like this because I imagine the closing of connection is due to it taking too long. Or is it something else? Like the server knows it's not a human caller or such? Say the site is cnn or whatever and I am trying to parse a news article for meta-tag contents. And no I am not crawling: I am given a url and I am sifting through that one page.

Comment: There may be several reasons for closing the connection - the server expects a user agent string or some cookie that you get from a different page. If you add the specific URL that you're trying to get, it would be possible to tell.

Comment: @learner, please if my answer helped you, please consider upvoting it and accepting it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

May be You have to send some header data as below. 
Please try it.

```
 Document doc = Jsoup
    .connect(url.trim())
    .timeout(3000)
    .header("Host", "someip")
    .header("Connection", "keep-alive")
    .header("Content-Length", "111")
    .header("Cache-Control", "max-age=0")
    .header("Accept",
            "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8")
    .header("User-Agent",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36")
    .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    .header("Referer", url.trim())
    .header("Accept-Encoding", "gzip,deflate,sdch")
    .header("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6")
    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36")
    .get();
```

Comment: `.userAgent(...)` is duplicate to `.header("User-Agent",....)`. According to the documentation, the `userAgent` method "Set the request user-agent header."

Answer (score 1):

I have absolutely no idea why, but the problem stops when I do

```
Connection connection = Jsoup.connect(url);
Document doc = connection.get();
Elements metas = doc.getElementsByTag("meta");
...
```

Instead of

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
Elements metas = doc.getElementsByTag("meta");
...
```

It makes completely no sense to me. But it is what it is. I have heard of "constructors escaping", which is what lead me to do the separation. And while this is probably not the same thing, but some similar type of voodoo may be happening under the hood that I just don't understand.

Comment: You are reusing the connection object, makes sense to me.